# CS50 Speller has a memory leak somewhere... and I can't find it

Tags: c, cs50

I am currently taking CS50x and am on Pset5: Speller. My code works as intended, however when I run the check50 function my program fails Valgrind.

This is particularly confusing to me because when I run Valgrind on my program with the help50, it passes with no memory leaks. I ran help50 Valgrind on my program after changing the default dictionary to the dictionaries/small, and it still passed.

Here is my code and the error log I get from check50. I believe the Valgrind error is from not using fclose() on the file, but if I include fclose() then my program fails when ran with a "munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer".

If anyone could help me out or had any idea where I should look I would be most grateful!

```
// Implements a dictionary's functionality

#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "dictionary.h"

// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
}
node;

// Number of bucket for Hash Table
const unsigned int N = 676;

// Hash table
node *table[N];

int word_counter = 0;

// Returns true if word is in dictionary, else false
bool check(const char *word)
{
    // TODO
    int index = hash(word);
    node *cursor = table[index];
    //printf("cursor: %s\n", cursor->word);

    while (cursor != NULL)
    {
        if (strcasecmp(word, cursor->word) == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
    cursor = cursor->next;

    }

    return false;
}

// Hashes word to a number
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    // TODO: Improve this hash function

    unsigned int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        if (word[0] == i + 'a' || word[0] == i + 'A')
        {
            index += i * 26;
        }

        if (word[1] == i + 'a' || word[1] == i + 'A')
        {
            index += i;
        }
    }

return index;
}

// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    FILE *dict_file = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if (dict_file == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }

    table_clear();

    // Use fscanf() to look at each string in the dictionary and store to buffer
    char *buffer = malloc(sizeof(LENGTH + 1));
    if (buffer == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }
    while (fscanf(dict_file, "%s", buffer) != EOF)
    {
        // Create a new memory space for each dictionary word, and store it here
        node *n = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if (n == NULL)
        {
            free(buffer);
            return false;
        }
        // Copy each word from buffer to the location (*dict_entry).word
        strcpy(n->word, buffer);
        n->next = NULL;

        // Use hash function to find the hash value of the dictionary word
        int index = hash(n->word);
        if (table[index] != NULL)
        {
            n->next = table[index];
        }
        table[index] = n;
        n = NULL;
        free(n);
        word_counter++;
    }
    //fclose(dict_file); <----- If activate, this line causes the munmap_chunk: invalid pointer error
    free(buffer);
    return true;
}

// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded, else 0 if not yet loaded
unsigned int size(void)
{
    return word_counter;
}

// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool unload(void)
{
     for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
     {
        node *cursor = table[i];
        while (cursor != NULL)
        {
            cursor = cursor->next;
            free(table[i]);
            table[i] = cursor;
        }

        free(cursor);
     }

    return true;
}

// Sets every value in table to NULL
void table_clear(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        table[i] = NULL;
    }
    return;
}
```

```
**Cause valgrind tests failed; see log for more information

LOG:
running valgrind --show-leak-kinds=all --xml=yes --xml-file=/tmp/tmpr2rknwok -- ./speller substring/dict substring/text...
checking for output "MISSPELLED WORDS\n\nca\ncats\ncaterpill\ncaterpillars\n\nWORDS MISSPELLED: 4\nWORDS IN DICTIONARY: 2\nWORDS IN TEXT: 6\n"...
checking that program exited with status 0...
checking for valgrind errors...
Invalid write of size 1: (file: dictionary.c, line: 88)
Invalid read of size 1: (file: dictionary.c, line: 99)
472 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 1: (file: dictionary.c, line: 74)
```

See above for exlaination

Comment: What is `"dictionary.h"`? We probably can't help you debug this without being able to compile it.

Comment: You use `hash` before you've declared it so it gets an implicit declaration (which is not correct). Undefined behavior right there. It's the same with `table_clear`. Since there are no circular dependencies between the functions, just move the function definitions of `hash` and `table_clear` to _above_ the functions that uses those functions. Also, enable more warnings when compiling. Your compiler _should_ be able to tell you about this. Perhaps you have the declarations of those functions in `"dictionary.h"`. I can't tell since I can't see that file.

Comment: `while(fscanf(dict_file, "%s", buffer) != EOF)` has _two_ mistakes: 1) It will write out of bounds if it reads a word that requires more space than you've got in `buffer`. 2) You should check for `== 1` instead of `!= EOF`

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem. Your posted code does not fulfill this criteria, because it is incomplete. You are not showing us the code for `dictionary.h`.

Comment: The memory error on `fclose()` is probably caused by a corrupted heap.  There are numerous lines of code that are subject to buffer overruns:  `fscanf(dict_file, "%s", buffer)` and `strcpy(n->word, buffer);` do not handle strings longer than `LENGTH` safely.

Comment: @AndrewHenle -> ok, that is a good theory. One thing I would say is that for this problem we told specifically that no word will be longer than 45 letters, so if LENGTH equals 45, buffer size being LENGTH + 1 should be sufficient right?

Comment: @ZachAnderson Except that your `buffer` isn't 45 + 1 `char`s big. See my answer.

Comment: Thank you AndrewHenle and TedLyngmo, both your answers pointed me in the right direction. I spent hours on this and don't think I would have caught that beginner mistake without your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are numerous problems with the program as pointed out in the comments, but the most likely culprit for the valgrind error report is this dynamic allocation:

```c
char *buffer = malloc(sizeof(LENGTH + 1));
```

It allocates the `sizeof` the *expression* `(LENGTH + 1)` number of bytes, which is most likely the same as doing `sizeof(int)` - which is often 4 - and 4 bytes isn't going to be able to store words longer than 3 `char`s. I say most likely because I don't know the type of `LENGTH`, but I'm assuming it's an `int`, and in that case, you effectively do `char *buffer = malloc(sizeof(int));`.

It should be:

```c
char *buffer = malloc(LENGTH + 1);
```

Comment: There we go, hopefully that is better and your answer is the accepted one Ted. Thanks again!